# How to set endorse policy in fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In this tutorial https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/endorsement-policies.html?highlight=endorsement%20policy
I know that

- AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member', 'Org3.member') requests 1 signature
  from each of the three principals
- OR('Org1.member', 'Org2.member') requests 1 signature from either one
  of the two principals
- OR('Org1.member', AND('Org2.member', 'Org3.member')) requests either
  one signature from a member of the Org1 MSP or 1 signature    from a
  member of the Org2 MSP and 1 signature from a member of the    Org3
  MSP.
- "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"means requests 1 signature
  from each of the two principals

But now I  requests all signature from each of the  principals. so how can set this endorse policy?

Answer (score 0):

You need to describe each and every endorsing principal, who needs to be in the endorsing policy.